# nginx binary files not available linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, 64-bit

Hi I have a requirement like that i should be able to install nginx in a machine that doesnt have internet connection so below are the approaches that i tried

- created a debian package from the source and tried installing
- downloaded the source(tar file) and tried make and make install
  But downloading the source requires internet and make and make install is not recommended
- The last option is to build nginx using binary file.
  I am not able to find any binaries for nginx.Am stuck here any help will be much helpful

Comment: Did you check out the [prebuilt Linux packages](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html)?

Comment: I should not be hitting a external url @devnull